# How can I give more weight to a tie in igraph r?

Tags: r, igraph

I'm new to igraph and was wondering if someone could help me. I have a friends network and want to show relationships between people. I want to give more weight to a relationship in which A lists B as a friend and also B lists A as a friend than if just one lists the other. Can anyone help me with how to do this?

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example.

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
library(igraph)
set.seed(1)
g <- erdos.renyi.game(10, 3/10, directed = TRUE)
E(g)$width <- ifelse(is.mutual(g), 4, 1)
plot(g)
```

[image]